# Cannot snapshot view UIKeyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that accesses the iTunes API. I have a button that opens up Apple Music in the Music app when selecting a music search.

Sometimes I get this error and it crashes the app when I select a music search:

```
Cannot snapshot view (<UIKeyboardImpl: 0x123d91a80; frame = (0 0; 414 226); layer = <CALayer: 0x174226160>>) with afterScreenUpdates:NO, because the view is not in a window. Use afterScreenUpdates:YES.
```

This is the code where the error happens:

```
@IBAction func openInStore() {
    if let url = URL(string: searchResult.storeURL) {
        //BUG: CANNOT SNAPSHOT VIEW UIKEYBOARD ERROR OCCURS SOMETIMES, CRASHES APP

        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

The error seems to say that the UIKeyboard is the problem but how do I get a reference to the keyboard? I don't understand why it says that. The keyboard is not open at all when I push the link that takes me to the Music app.

Comment: I'm quite sure that you're looking at the wrong error. This is a message that often shows when the current app enters background mode, and IOS is creating a temporary snapshot of your screen to use when the app is opened again. I would really try to look for some other error.

Comment: Yup, you're right. It was actually the music app that crashes when attempting to follow the iTunes link, not my app. It just seemed like my app was crashing because it occurred kinda during the transition.